# Easy way for creating custom livecd

Tags: usb, live-cd

I wondered if there's simpler way to create a custom live cd than this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

For example, when you create a live usb by startup disc creator, you have an option for allocating additional space for saving data.
Is it possible to insert a live usb, do some changes and then copy contents of this usb to a CD?

By 'changes' I mean key shortcuts, user interface settings (so home directory) and additional packages. The latter is less important.

And the version of OS is not very important for me, it has to be Xubuntu, but it does not have to be the latest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu Customization Kit

```
sudo apt-get install uck
```

Never used it though, but found it here : http://www.howtogeek.com/109736/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/